# Selenium InternetExplorerDriver add cookie

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can't add cookie in InternetExplorerDriver.

```
InternetExplorerDriver driver = .....;
driver.manage().add(myCookie);
```

exception:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to add cookie to page
 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Comment: Have you fixed that?

Comment: Have this at Selenium WebDriver and IEDriver 2.52 but for .net.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the website you want to add cookies to before adding a cookie.

so your code should look like:

```
InternetExplorerDriver driver = .....;
driver.get("http://my.testing.site");
driver.manage().add(myCookie);
```

I think there was an issues raised in the bug tracker for this, i'll see if I can dig it out.

**Edit**

Here's one of the tickets raised:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1953

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is then I try add cookie, I have this exception WebDriverException

Comment: So have you actually loaded the page, you will get an Exception thrown if you try to add a cookie before loading the page.

Comment: No. I load the page like this driver.get("http://my.testing.site");
after try to add cookie and it failes

Comment: new Cookie("myCookie","value")